# Why is my Comment App Only Working on SOME Blogger Posts?

Tags: facebook-apps, blogger, facebook-comments

The app was working totally fine...and then I reinstalled the app code in the Blogger template to be BELOW the Blogger comment box...now only some pages have the Facebook plugin...No clue why. Help? website is wwnrockport .com

Answer (score 1):

It May Be Helpful For Check It Out . [Use Facebook Yahoo And Google+ Comment system together](http://mhskp786.blogspot.com/2013/11/enable-facebook-comments-without.html)